# NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFoundException in Spring Boot App w/ Gradle in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm new to creating a web application using Spring Boot with Gradle and I've been getting along alright, then all of a sudden without knowledge of what's changed, I can't run it as a Spring Boot app and I get a popup error that says "Error: A JNI error has occurred. Please check your installation and try again." I hit okay and then another popup occurs that says "A Java exception has occurred". I hit okay again and then the console reads:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at 
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

I have `import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;` and I'm not getting any errors in the code until I compile so I know something is getting lost when I compile it. I've read about possible errors in the class path file? I'm not sure where that is or how to edit that. It's all new to me and I've just hit a brick wall. I've even downloaded other JARs to import and then I get the same error but for a different class and it's just an infinite loop of errors.

My build.gradle file looks something like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

What other information will you need to assist me with this? Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: @LHCHIN I've cleaned my project, but the rebuild option is greyed out.